# ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1855:in `sub!': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, csv, utf-8

I'm not sure how to debug this...

ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1855:in `sub!': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Any suggestions? Should I try to convert the file first?

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV file? ASCII and ISO-8891-1 should both be valid Unicode.

Comment: I think it was ISO-8891-1 in the end I force converted it into utf-8 with a sublimetext2 encoding converter and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually converting to UTF-8 in a text editor solved the problem for me.